# Modelling Mie Theory: Resources

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, resource-recommendations, simulations, scattering-cross-section, nanoscience

I am currently working on simulating the scattering of light from nanoparticles. Are there any resources like books/ handouts/ videos that explain Mie Theory in depth?